# Flutter: how to convert a `StatefulWidget` to an `ImageProvider`

Tags: flutter, image

This seems like it should be simple but I cannot seem to find an answer.

When I have a Widget (Stateful or Stateless) that I'm using as an image (for example: `SvgPicture`, `CachedNetworkImage`, or `FadeInImage`) and I need to have an `ImageProvider`, how can I make that conversion?

For a `FadeInImage` I can use `FadeInImage( image: i, placeholder: p).image`.

`SvgPicture` and `CachedNetworkImage` do not have a `.image` property.

###### Is there a generic way to convert a widget to an `ImageProvider` ?

---

I tried `ImageProvider( widget )` but `ImageProvider` is abstract - so another way to ask this question could be:

Is there an instance of `ImageProvider` that simply takes a widget as a parameter ?

Comment: You could use `AssetImage` widget as your image provider, just make sure to cast its type to `ImageProvider`

Answer (score 0):

For CachedNetworkImage you can use CachedNetworkImageProvider("YOUR URL HERE")

For FadeInImage you can use AssetImage("") as your Image Provide.

I am not sure about SvgPicture but I'm sure you can find it in the documentation given on Pub.dev